# CSS animation keyframes overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am not adept at css animations at all. I am trying to animate 4 text elements in

tags using the code from https://codepen.io/nucliweb/pen/ymedj as a reference.

I want them to fade in one after the other. Basically a text slider. Hence I tried doing this but unfortunately cannot get the 4th

to behave like the 1st 3. I am sure it is because the keyframes were written for 3 elements and I added the 4th hence causing text overlap issues.

Could someone please correct the keyframes value such that there is no overlap as is happening if a 4th paragraph is added.
Html

```
<p class="item-1">All showing good.</p>
<p class="item-2">Until the 4th element is added</p>

<p class="item-3">Because keyframes values are no longer adding up</p>
<p class="item-4"> I created this as I wanted to add this text to end the slider and all hell broke loose </p>
```

The css is:
        @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

```
body { 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
 color: #cecece;
background: #222;
overflow: hidden;
}

.item-1, 
.item-2, 
.item-3,
.item-4 {
position: absolute;
 display: block;
top: 2em;

width: 60%;

font-size: 2em;

animation-duration: 20s;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.item-1{
animation-name: anim-1;
}

.item-2{
animation-name: anim-2;
}

.item-3{
animation-name: anim-3;
}
.item-4{
animation-name: anim-4; /*added by me*/
}
  @keyframes anim-1 { /*for anim 1,2 and 3 the code runs flawless.*/
  0%, 8.3% { opacity: 0; }
  8.3%,25% {  opacity: 1; }
  33.33%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
 }

@keyframes anim-2 {
0%, 33.33% {  opacity: 0; }
41.63%, 58.29% {  opacity: 1; }
66.66%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes anim-3 { /*code is screwed on adding anim-4*/
0%, 66.66% { opacity: 0; }
74.96%, 91.62% {  opacity: 1; }
100% {  opacity: 0; }
}
  @keyframes anim-4 {          /*PLEASE GUIDE ABOUT THE VALUES NEEDED HERE*/
0%, 66.66% { opacity: 0; } /*PREVIOUS VALUES MUST CHANGE /*
74.96%, 91.62% {  opacity: 1; }/*BUT I AM CONFUSED ABOUT THE KEYFRAMES*/
100% {  opacity: 0; }
}
```

Could someone kindly please provide the keyframe values such that no overlap happens.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, this is a pure math problem. You have X frames, each frame has 25% of its time (which is 100% / X) with `opacity: 0`, followed by 50% of this time with `opacity: 1`, followed by 25% of this time with `opacity: 0`.

You can work the calculations yourself and write elaborate `calc`s to provide for changing number of frames, but initial 8.3% (25% of 100%/3) would then become 25% of 100%/4 (since you have 4 items now), or 6.25%. And so on.

So,

`.item-1 {
    animation-name: anim-1;
}
.item-2 {
    animation-name: anim-2;
}
.item-3 {
    animation-name: anim-3;
}
.item-4 {
    animation-name: anim-4;
}
@keyframes anim-1 { /* first quarter: 0 … 100% / X */
    0%, 0% { opacity: 0; }
    6.25%, 18.75% { opacity: 1; }  /* 100% / 16 … 100% / 16 * 3 */
    25%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes anim-2 { /* second quarter */
    0%, 25% {  opacity: 0; }
    31.25%, 43.75% {  opacity: 1; } /* 100% / 16 * 5 … 100% / 16 * 7 */
    50%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes anim-3 { /* third quarter */
    0%, 50% { opacity: 0; }
    56.25%, 68.75% {  opacity: 1; } /* 100% / 16 * 9 … 100% / 16 * 11 */
    75%, 100% {  opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes anim-4 { /* fourth quarter: 100% / X * (X-1) … 100% */
    0%, 75% { opacity: 0; }
    81.25%, 93.75% {  opacity: 1; }  /* 100% / 16 * 13 … 100% / 16 * 15 */
    100%, 100% {  opacity: 0; }
}`

Comment: I came to almost  the same thing after a bit of learning about keyframes. Your code seems smoother. Thanks a lot for helping out :)